# How would you find the roots of a linear interpolation in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, signals, interpolation

I'm working on calculating the full width at half maximum for light curves with irregular shapes. My approach right now is to

- fit a spline (`scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline`) to the data (minus half maximum, so that y = 0 *is* the half max)
- find the roots of the spline (`UnivariateSpline.roots()`)
- find the difference between the first and last roots to determine the width of the curve at half max

The `roots` method is only available for cubic splines, but I need the spline to be linear, or else I get results like the image below (due to the spacing of the data points). I should note that I'm working with hundreds of datasets, so manually selecting these "roots" is not quite feasible.

Does anyone have any tricks to find the roots of a *linear* spline (or all of the x-values for a given y value)? Many thanks!

[image: A plot showing the discrepancy between the true flux and the cubic spline.]

Comment: Can you just loop over the y-values to find y[n]<half and y[n+1]>half (reversed for downward crossings)?  Then just linearly interpolate to get the x value at y == half.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `make_interp_spline_(..., k=1)` to get a BSpline object, convert to PPoly via PPoly.from_spline() and the result has a .roots method.

Alternatively, as other answers suggest, just find the relevant interval and solve for a root of linear segment.